# Input readonly backspace issue

Tags: html, input, readonly

In my `input` element, when I navigate to the element and enter the backspace key using keyboard, it navigates to the previous page, when I set the input is `readonly`.

My code is below. Please share your knowledge.

```
<div class="div1">
    <label class="div1" for="inputfor">cash:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cashinput" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can't get cursor in `readonly` field. and pressing `backspace` will call `browser's` back button event and will redirect to the previous Page.

Comment: What is the purpose of hitting backspace when the textbox is readonly?

Comment: @PankitKapadia Not true! Cursor can be placed inside the readonly textbox. But it won't do anything when backspace is pressed

Comment: @aspirin True. This question has no sense.

Comment: @asprin - That depends on the browser.

Comment: @Aesthete Hmm..didn't knew that. I can use the cursor on FF. Maybe in other browsers it won't allow

Comment: i remove the ready only its work fine. but i need to the particular text only read only mode. no one call function when press the backspace

Comment: @user279 - better you use `disabled="disabled"` instead of readonly.

Comment: Using `disabled` is not recommended as it wont post the value on form submit

Comment: @asprin - Sorry i was wrong. as Aesthete said it depends on browser. :)

Comment: Wow guys! I even could not understand the question. Syntactically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected and correct behavior for an input with a readonly attribute.

An input with this attribute cannot be modified, it can only be viewed, you can access the content by tabbing and copying, but that is it.

Remove the readonly attribute if it's not needed.

Comment: but i need to that particular text box only read only mode. user can not change the value.

Comment: Then there is no bug or issue, this is standard behavior.

Comment: I don't understand, you don't want the input to be modifiable by users, but you want them to be able to delete the content? This makes no sense!

Comment: my user only rights to copy the content that only i give the cursor in my text box. but my user try to remove the text using backspace it will be does to the previous page

Comment: You could use some javascript to disable the backspace altogether, but then users who use it as a navigation tool are going to wonder what happened.

Comment: Chrome and Mozilla do not take you to the previous page when you press Backspace while a readonly field has focus. This is the behavior I expect and what makes sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanVance It seems browsers/OSws have changed their backspace behavior recently.

Comment: @JonathanVance, Exactly right, because backspace as a navigational key is poor design, and frustrating to many users that have filled out a form, only to loose data because they hit the backspace key in the wrong field.

Answer (score 34):

I know that this question was asked 2 years back. Since I have a solution that worked for me, I am tempted to share it with everyone.

The fix is quite simple:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" readonly="readonly"/>
```

The event.preventDefault() will stop the backspace from navigating away from the page and you can also select and copy the text.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its Fixed Alreay

Comment: This is the real answer for the question.

Answer (score 4):

You could always just keep the input field readonly disallow input altogether.

```
<div class="div1">
    <label class="div1" for="inputfor">cash:</label>
    <input type="text" id="cashinput" onkeydown="return false;" readonly="readonly"/>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working but i need to just copy function through the keyboard

Comment: @user279 - I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: onkeydown="return false; using this its works fine. but i need to copy the text from the text area i didnt access the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

This line helped me:

```
onkeydown="if(this.readOnly) event.preventDefault();"
```

Answer (score -2):

if you are in page because of location.href = "new/page/url";

use location.replace("new/page/url") instead.

location.href = "new/page/url"; // loads new page and saves current page as history in IE

refer 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location